# Is it possible to configure Laravel repeat attempt to send email in case of smtp error happened?

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I have Symfony project and email component there keep trying to send an email until it wouldn't be send. In case of error while sending system just don't mark email as sent and next email sending iteration it try to send it again. It gives me confidence that important email would be delivered.

I don't sure that such way of email handling configured by default at Laravel, what should I change to do email handling like Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Laravel queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) for sending e-mails? The queuing system has a built-in retry mechanism, which would solve the issue you're having.

Comment: Do I get you right: if while sending smtp reply with an error then email class will throw an Exception and queue handle that? Does it work with "sync" queue?(I doubt that but we have to use it right now due to limits of hosting)

Comment: Yes you are right; if a job fails due to an exception, it is requeued for later processing. From what I know the sync queue does not support the retry mechanism that the async queue does.